# Unexpected token export

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, systemjs

As a new Angular rookie, I am trying to upgrade my previously working Angular 2.0.0-beta17 web-app to Angular 2.3.0. Now I have a problem while loading/booting the app.

Here's my setup:

For solution purposes, I copied all node_modules in the web directory for now. So no files should be missing.

```
(web directory)
├── index.html
├── js
│   ├── boot.js
│   ├── boot.js.map
│   ├── feedback-form.component.js
│   ├── feedback-form.component.js.map
│   ├── feedback-form.service.js
│   ├── feedback-form.service.js.map
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── *all node modules*
│   ├── ui-molecule.component.js
│   └── ui-molecule.component.js.map
└── views
    ├── feedback-form.html
    └── ui-molecule.html
```

**package.json**

I discarded and rebuilt the modules folder every time I changed the package.json. so it is current.

```
{
  "name": "FeedbackFormWebApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Martin Labuschin",
  "description": "...",
  "repository": "...",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "2.3.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.41",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-rc.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "3.1.3",
    "gulp-webserver": "^0.9.1",
    "del": "2.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "3.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "2.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.3.0",
    "typescript": "2.1.4",
    "minimatch": "3.0.2",
    "graceful-fs": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

**index.html** (only the script part):

I set the paths accordingly to my file/directory structure.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='/js/lib/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='/js/lib/systemjs/dist/system.src.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  System.config({
    packages: {
      js: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    },
    paths: {
      '@angular/*': 'js/lib/@angular/*/index.js',
      'rxjs/*': 'js/lib/rxjs/*.js'
    }
  });
  System.import('js/boot').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
```

The **boot.ts** (which is successfully translated to js by my gulpfile) tries to load angular-core at line 1.

```
import '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';

import { FeedbackFormComponent } from './feedback-form.component';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(FeedbackFormComponent);
```

Everything before System.import (index.html) *seems* to be properly prepared. 
There are lib files loaded, no 404s or so. But this is the error I keep getting:

```
> (index):28 Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected token export  SyntaxError:
> Unexpected token export
>       at eval (<anonymous>)
>       at e.invoke (http://localhost:8000/js/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js:1:15094)
>       at n.run (http://localhost:8000/js/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js:1:12458)
>       at http://localhost:8000/js/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js:1:10100
>       at e.invokeTask (http://localhost:8000/js/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js:1:15723)
>       at n.runTask (http://localhost:8000/js/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js:1:13076)
>       at a (http://localhost:8000/js/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js:1:9146)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.invoke (http://localhost:8000/js/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js:1:16876)
>   Evaluating http://localhost:8000/js/lib/@angular/core/index.js  Error
> loading http://localhost:8000/js/lib/@angular/core/index.js as
> "@angular/core" from http://localhost:8000/js/boot.js
>       at eval (<anonymous>)
>       at e.invoke (http://localhost:8000/js/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js:1:15094)
>       at n.run (http://localhost:8000/js/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js:1:12458)
>       at http://localhost:8000/js/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js:1:10100
>       at e.invokeTask (http://localhost:8000/js/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js:1:15723)
>       at n.runTask (http://localhost:8000/js/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js:1:13076)
>       at a (http://localhost:8000/js/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js:1:9146)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.invoke (http://localhost:8000/js/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js:1:16876)
>   Evaluating http://localhost:8000/js/lib/@angular/core/index.js  Error
> loading http://localhost:8000/js/lib/@angular/core/index.js as
> "@angular/core" from http://localhost:8000/js/boot.js
```

I searched Google and Stackoverflow for hours now and no solution to similar problems is working for this case. How can this be solved? Thanks so much in advance!

PS. I can provide the repository, if necessary. Please just ask!

Comment: where is your module ts ?

Comment: The is no module ts. It's not created or referenced. Where exactly do you expect this to be placed or to be used?

Comment: You shouldn't move `node_modules`. This way you just broke paths.

Comment: The are no broken paths. All files are loaded properly (according to my Inspector). Also, I just *copied* the modules folder from the app-root to the web-folder, I did not move it.

Comment: bootstrapModule command expects passing module class not component class

Comment: this looks to be the next issue. i will look into it. thanks so far

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As we can see from the error stack trace, it fails parsing `@angular/core/index.js`. While you are tranpiling your own source files, angular is deployed as ES2015 modules with ES5 syntax. You have to use a pure ES5 version, which I suggest the deployed UMD files.

Update your systemjs.config.js like this:

```
// map tells the System loader where to look for things
map: {
  // our app is within the app folder
  app: 'app',

  // angular bundles
  '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
  '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
  '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
```

Or rather use a existing working setup (like angular quickstart), it is a good start. Or yet use angular-cli, this is better for the long term.

Source: https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular/angular.io/b3c65a9/public/docs/_examples/_boilerplate/systemjs.config.web.js

Comment: looks good so far. but i also added http and platform-browser-dynamic the same way, since inspector showed, it asked for it. but it now breaks here:

(index):33 Error: (SystemJS) Cannot read property '__platform_browser_private__' of undefined

Comment: In RC they introduced NgModules, so I urge you to start over with angular-cli to get up and running. Then migrate your former .ts files. I pointed why the error happens but it isn't productive to keep your current setup.